# Creating an Angular Chart using AJAX

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to create a chart using the example code below. This works but I'd like to create a chart dynamically using AJAX. If I insert the chart using AJAX the chart does not load. I would like to know how I can change the below code to allow me to dynamically create an Angular Chart using AJAX?

Example HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.css"></link>
</head>

<body>

<!-- If I try to insert the below using AJAX the chart does not load -->
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ChartController as vm"> 
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="vm.barChart.data" chart-labels="vm.barChart.labels"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
angular
  .module('app', ['chart.js'])
  .controller('ChartController', ChartController);

function ChartController() {
  var vm = this;

  // Data
  vm.barChart = {
    labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
    series: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
    data: [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ]
  };
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** My question is marked as duplicate but I'm sure this is different as I'm asking how to 'create' not 'update' a chart after the DOM has already been loaded. I think I should have been more clear, I'm not asking how to update the chart data using AJAX, I'm asking how to actually 'create' the chart using AJAX. I can only seem to create the chart when DOM loads for the first time, not after.

Comment: how do you plan on inserting your data? with a form? from other resources?  why can't you just append your data without AJAX?

Comment: I'm using Drupal to develop an admin dashboard that loads content on the fly after pressing various buttons. So I'm using Drupals AJAX framework to insert the data. Do you know how I can create charts after the DOM has been loaded?

Comment: it's best to avoid AJAX with angularjs, you can make asynchronous calls with `$http.get("/source/some_database_call.php").then((res)=>{/* populate $scope with res.data */})`

Comment: I think I'm a little out of my depth with this one so will probably look for an alternative chart library. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: see if [fusioncharts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex1) could be useful

Comment: If you need AJAX in AngularJS you can use `$http` service as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, you could to use [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

> **AngularJS services** are substitutable objects that are wired together
>   using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and
>   share code across your app.

You can declare an AngularJS Service by this way:

```
.service("MyService", ["$http", function($http) {
  return {
    getMyData: function() { // This service method can be called from the controller.
      return $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/4fade791505e812eae1a3fea2cde6ac4/raw/d73d8eb12cff8911b6b7c681718a760129ae1299/angular-chart-data.json", null, {
          responseType: "json"
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

**Where:**

> - "MyService": Service name. You can inject this service through this name to the AngularJS Controller.
> - "$http": [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http): A core AngularJS service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's
>     XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP. The [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service is a
>     function which takes a single argument that is used to generate an
>     HTTP request and returns a promise.

Inject the AngujarJS Service in the AngularJS Controller:

```
.controller("ChartController", ["MyService", ChartController]);
```

To call the AngularJS Service method from the AngularJS Controller and handle the received data, you could use this:

```
MyService.getMyData().then(function(response) {
    // Data.
    vm.barChart = response.data;

  }, function(response) {
    console.log("Error: " + response);
});
```

AJAX requires an URL that could return a `JSON` object, in this case.

**URL:** https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/4fade791505e812eae1a3fea2cde6ac4/raw/d73d8eb12cff8911b6b7c681718a760129ae1299/angular-chart-data.json

**JSON:**

```
{
    "labels": ["2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012"],
    "series": ["Series A", "Series B"],
    "data": [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ]
}
```

See this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ChartController as vm">
      <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="vm.barChart.data" chart-labels="vm.barChart.labels"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    angular
      .module("app", ["chart.js"])


      .service("MyService", ["$http", function($http) {
        return {
          getMyData: function() {
            return $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/4fade791505e812eae1a3fea2cde6ac4/raw/d73d8eb12cff8911b6b7c681718a760129ae1299/angular-chart-data.json", null, {
              responseType: "json"
            });
          }
        };
      }])

      .controller("ChartController", ["MyService", ChartController]);

    function ChartController(MyService) {
      var vm = this;


      MyService.getMyData().then(function(response) {

        // Data.
        vm.barChart = response.data;

      }, function(response) {
        console.log("Error: " + response);
      });


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get chart data dynamically via ajax.

- Key is to set the data property of your chart via another function.
- To get data via ajax it makes sense to put this functionality into it's own service and link this service to the controller.
- the getData() function of the service can be triggered anytime by buttons or periodically via timers ($timeout)

In this example I used an external file called data.json with the following content:

```
[
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
]
```

Happy coding!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/dist/angular-chart.min.css"></link>
</head>

<body>

<!-- If I try to insert the below using AJAX the chart does not load -->
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ChartController as vm"> 
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="vm.barChart.data" chart-labels="vm.barChart.labels"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
angular
  .module('app', ['chart.js'])
  .service('ChartService', ['$http', ChartService])
  .controller('ChartController', ['ChartService', ChartController]);

function ChartService($http) {
    this.getData = function (callback) {
        $http.get('data.json').success(function(response) {
            console.log("Got data: " + response);
            if (callback) callback(response);
        });
    };
}

function ChartController(chartService) {
  var vm = this;

  // Data
  vm.barChart = {
    labels: ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
    series: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
    data: []
  };

  function callback(data) {
    vm.barChart.data = data;
  }

  chartService.getData(callback);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```